# I want to disable a tinymce textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, tinymce

I have a tinymce textbox which I want to disable and again enable on a button click through ASP.NET.

When it is disabled it should be read only.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this thread](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=20281) of the tinymce forum. This might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'Disable');
```

See also [Enable Disable (Readonly) TinyMCE Editor using JavaScript or Server Side](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/655046/Enable-Disable-Readonly-TinyMCE-Editor-using-JavaScript-or-Server-Side/)